# How can I remove all xml attribute values with PHP?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

What is the best way to remove all attribute **values** (not attributes) from xml file using PHP SimpleXML?

Conditions:
The input xml file is nested with known attribute names. 
The output xml file retains all attribute names but not values.

Example xml:

```
<xml>
 <animal>
  <dog weight="">
   <dogChild1 weight=""></dogChild1>
   <dogChild2 weight=""></dogChild2>
  </dog>
  <cat weight="">
  </cat>
 </animal>
 <...>
 </...>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I've understood correctly, but you want to load the XML, retain the structure but remove the values? E.g.

XML file:

```
<EXAMPLE><PETS><PET><TYPE>Dog</TYPE><AGE>2</AGE></PET><PET><TYPE>CAT</TYPE><AGE>6 Months</AGE></PET></PETS></EXAMPLE>
```

So with that file content, you want to remove the values that have been populated in `TYPE` and `AGE`? If so, something like this would probably work:

```
$objPetsXml = simplexml_load_string($strFileContents);

foreach($objPetsXml->PETS->PET as $objPet) {
    $objPet->TYPE = "";
    $objPet->AGE = "";
}

// Build your new XML and do whatever
```

Does that make any sense?